# Checking if user has liked my facebook page without app id

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Is there a way to find out if a user has liked my facebook fan page without setting up a facebook app ?

I can track when a user likes my facebook fan page, but i want to show different messages when a person steps in my website if he has already liked my page and a different if he hasn't.

Also i don't want to set up a facebook app to detect it.

Comment: 1. You need to setup a Facebook App for a Facebook user to grant you permission to access their data.
2. Like gating is against Facebook Platform Policy. You cannot alter content based on whether a user has liked a page or not. Therefore you would not get permission to use the user_likes scope in App Review.

Comment: Hi @HeyDarren, so it means that the answer is "It's not possible". Right?

Comment: Exactly! It's not possible.